# Averaging Vectors from Documents

Tags: python, vector, average, spacy

How could I use the medium-sized spaCy model en_core_web_md to parse through a folder of documents to get individual vectors from each single word document, and then average them together?

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to load all the docs into the list using python file io/op.

```
#documents loaded into the python list.
documents_list = ['Hello, world','Here are two sentences.']
#Iterate over each document and initiate nlp instance.
for doc in documents_list:
    doc_nlp = nlp(doc)
    #this gives the average vector of each document.
    print(doc_nlp.vector)
    for token in doc_nlp:
        #this gives the text of each word in the doc and their vector.
        print(token.text,token.vector)
```

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: For the documents_list, could I link the file path to the folder containing the text files and have it go through each text file?

Comment: Also, Im working with several hundred documents in the file, so how could I average the values it gives me?

Comment: @Gerold so the average done automatically with calling of doc_nlp.vecort

Comment: And first read all the document into the list by going through all the files then process list as provided in the answer (your all documents should be stored in the document_list -- list).